# Failed to resolve: com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:3.0.0 and Failed to resolve: com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.0.0

Tags: android, quickblox

how can i resolve this 2 problems [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use version 3.0 not 3.0.0. And you can include only need QuickBlox Android SDK module without transitive modules (starting from version 2.6.1) in your case you can  connect only chat module, module core will be connected automatically.